# R web-scraping only half of texts in dataframe and filter() not working

Tags: r, web-scraping, dplyr, rvest

I'm trying to pull text from ~8500 bills, but the dataframe that results only has about 4,000 with actual text in the text column. I thought this was because of user agent issues, but it continues to happen. How do I pull all bill texts? (I do recommend interrupting it after a small amount of time so you don't have to wait for the whole df to run, but still get enough rows pulled that you can see what I mean.)

In the meantime, I tried to use the dataframe I do have by filtering out the rows that had no data or "missing" data. When I try `dfNum <- df1 %>% filter(text != "" | text != "missing")` it keeps all the rows. Why is that happening and how can I get it to work?

Even if I can't get the above answered. I could probably cobble something together if the filter function worked.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(purrr)
library(curl)
library(httr)

#Start off with a base URL and an empty list
base_url <- "https://www.congress.gov/quick-search/legislation?wordsPhrases=healthcare&wordVariants=on&congressGroups%5B%5D=0&congresses%5B%5D=all&legislationNumbers=&legislativeAction=&sponsor=on&representative=&senator=&houseCommittee%5B%5D=hsif00&q={%22chamber%22:%22House%22,%22type%22:%22bills%22,%22subject%22:%22Health%22,%22house-committee%22:%22Energy+and+Commerce%22}&pageSize=250"
my_list <- ""

#Get all bill links for all 34 pages, one page at a time
for (i in 1:34) {
  
  url <- paste0(base_url, "&page=", i)
  print(url)
  url_links <- read_html(url) %>%
    html_nodes(".result-heading a") %>%
    html_attr("href")
  my_list <- append(my_list, url_links)
  #This wasn't working properly before so I'm wiping the temp variables and making the system rest for 1.5 seconds each time it finishes one iteration, 
  #BUT I had to change it bc of the user_agent() issues.
  rm(url)
  rm(url_links)
  gc()
  Sys.sleep(sample(10, 1) * 0.1)
}

length(unique(my_list))

#Turn list into dataframe
df1 <- as.data.frame(my_list)

#Keeping unique values and removing first row (which is blank from the empty list)
df1 <- df1 %>% 
  distinct() %>% 
  filter(my_list != "")

#Mutate to get full base url
df1 <- df1 %>% 
  mutate(cleaned_url = gsub("\\?.*", "", my_list)) %>% 
  mutate(full_url = paste0("https://www.congress.gov", cleaned_url, "/text/ih"))

#Clean up the df, make bill # column and making one url column
df1 <- df1 %>% 
  separate(cleaned_url, sep="house-bill/", into = c("remove", "bill"), remove=TRUE) %>% 
  select(bill, full_url) %>% 
  mutate(text = "")
#progress bar for loop & user_agent change
pb = txtProgressBar(min = 0, max = length(df1), initial = 0) 
httr::GET
ua <- "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.15; rv:99.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/99.0"
congress <- GET("https://www.congress.gov",
               user_agent(ua))
congress$request$options$useragent
#Actual text of the bills in a loop
for (i in 1:nrow(df1)) {
  
  text <- read_html(df1$full_url[i]) %>% 
    html_nodes(".generated-html-container") %>% 
    html_text(trim = T)
  
  if (length(text) > 0) {
    df1$text[i] <- text
  }
  else {
    df1$text[i] <- "missing"
  }
  
  rm(text)
  gc()
  Sys.sleep(sample(10, 1) * 0.1)
  setTxtProgressBar(pb,i)
  close(pb)
}
#view(df1)
length(df1$text)
sum(is.na(df1$text))
sum(df1$text=="")
sum(df1$text=="missing")
dfNum <- df1 %>% 
  filter(text != "" | text != "missing")
dfNum2 <- df1 %>% 
  filter(text == "" | text == "missing")
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `rm` in a loop.

The following code should get you all the ~8500 bills from the 34 pages.

```
base_url <- "https://www.congress.gov/quick-search/legislation?wordsPhrases=healthcare&wordVariants=on&congressGroups%5B%5D=0&congresses%5B%5D=all&legislationNumbers=&legislativeAction=&sponsor=on&representative=&senator=&houseCommittee%5B%5D=hsif00&q={%22chamber%22:%22House%22,%22type%22:%22bills%22,%22subject%22:%22Health%22,%22house-committee%22:%22Energy+and+Commerce%22}&pageSize=250"
```

Create links for all pages.

```
url <- paste0(base_url, "&page=", 1:34)
```

Use `lapply` for extracting bill's url.

```
url_links <- lapply(url, function(x) {
  read_html(x) %>%
    html_nodes(".result-heading a") %>%
    html_attr("href") %>% unique() %>% paste0('https://www.congress.gov', .)
})
#convert list to vector
url_links = unlist(url_links)
```

Now extract text from each bill's url.

```
text = lapply(url_links, function(x) {
    read_html(x) %>% html_nodes('.main-wrapper') %>% html_nodes('p') %>% 
    html_text(trim = T)
})
```

Comment: I got this error: Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : 
  Timeout was reached: [www.congress.gov] Operation timed out after 10010 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received. After checking the web, it said I needed RSelenium. How would I go about that?

Comment: Check your internet connection, it may be slow. Using `rvest` is a much more faster approach than `RSelenium`